# How can I stop gnome-software from checking for updates when I log in?

Tags: apt, updates, login, gnome-software

Every time I log in `gnome-software` is using 100% of my cpu, and I assume it is because it checks for updates or something. Logging in is very slow, and I am not at all interested in these automatic update checks. I often update packages in terminal so I don't need this feature.

How can I disable it?

Comment: Thanks for the question. The speed doesn't bother me at all, but I don't like software notifications. I check updates when I want to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu's software updater is **not** GNOME Software! GNOME Software does not listen to Ubuntu's software updater settings. I know this because I've got Ubuntu's updater set to run every other week, but I keep getting updates daily.

I found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338421) on the Ubuntu forums, there is an edit on the original post with the solution to both problems. Use dconf-editor (may need to install), go to org.gnome.software, and uncheck "download-updates". GNOME Software should no longer check for updates, and Ubuntu's Updater should continue to update as usual. I'm not entirely sure, but I'm willing to bet you will need to log out and log back in for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling automatic updates can be done in the GUI:

```
-> System Settings 
-> Ubuntu Software & update 
-> Updates (tab) 
-> Automatic Check for updates 
-> Never
```

Comment: This solved my problem with slow login, but gnome-software is now using 100% of cpu a couple of seconds after I am logged in, why is this? Can I stop it from starting on login?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it inherits the Ubuntu system settings as per:

```
> System > Software &  Updates
```

in there, click on the "Updates" tab and choose "Never" for "Automatically check for updates".

This should give you what you want (but, then why ... ?)